# How to extract relevant data from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm using a table named "url2" with tje MySQL InnoDB Engine. I'm having so many data with full HTML of a Page, URL of the page, and so on.... When I use the following SQL query I am getting lot of results:

```
SELECT url FROM url2 WHERE html LIKE '%Yuva%' OR url LIKE '%Yuva%'
```

The search term yuva can be changes as user request
It will select lot of data, mostly which I don't need, how can i avoid that?
The out put of the above query is
www.123musiq.com
www.123musiq.com/home.html
www.123musiq.com/yuva.html
www.sensongs.com/
www.sensongs.com/hindi.html
www.sensongs.com/yuva.html

The Output i need is
According to the relevancy it should be sorted Like
www.123musiq.com/yuva.html
www.sensongs.com/yuva.html
www.sensongs.com/hindi.html

As from the comment of my Friend i change table to MyISAM,but i am geting 123musiq.com files first about 25 after that i am geting sensongs.how can i get 2 from 123musiq.com and 2 from sensongs.com,order by relevance

Comment: Well, you haven't told us what you're looking for in that data to explain why you don't want the entire result...

Comment: Can you provide the table schema and what specifically you are looking for from the data? Yuva tells us nothing about relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're asking for a [Full Text Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), which in MySQL are only available on MyISAM tables.

Since you're using InnoDB tables, the easiest solution is to create a new (MyISAM) table with only the text content and an index to join with the original table (this also helps with seek efficiency in some common cases).

Comment: How can we do that?is it fast? i am having data arount 1TB

Comment: it indexes the full text, so any such search hits the index, not the data.

Comment: check the docs, you have to create the index and use MATCH() queries.  just switching to MyISAM won't make any difference until you do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use LIMIT?

```
SELECT * FROM url2 WHERE html LIKE '%Yuva%' OR url LIKE '%Yuva%' LIMIT 2
```